# New Teams Issue: Problem reaching this app from the Left Navigation Bar

Tags: microsoft-teams, chatbot

This is a personal bot application which loads fine in Classic Teams from the Left navigation bar 'Apps'. But after using the New Teams (v23272.2707.2453.769), we are facing 'Problem reaching this App' issue when trying to open it via the Left Navigation Menu or from the Apps. Please note that it is working fine in the Chat window.

I tried by modifying the Manifest file but it still shows the issue. Upon checking the Teams logs using 'Collect Support Files' feature, it mentions this error: "PlatformErrorBoundary: Error message: Invalid static tab." But I have not added any Static tab in the current manifest file. Here is a sample of the current manifest file (I have changed the IDs and other personal info). Can you please have a look and help me out?

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.16/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
    "version": "2.0.1",
    "manifestVersion": "1.16",
    "id": "12345-3592-1234-5668-6789010",
    "packageName": "com.test.example",
    "name": {
        "short": "Test-App",
        "full": "Test-App"
    },
    "developer": {
        "name": "CompanyXYZ",
        "mpnId": "",
        "websiteUrl": "https://www.CompanyXYZ.com/",
        "privacyUrl": "https://www.CompanyXYZ.com/",
        "termsOfUseUrl": "https://www.CompanyXYZ.com/"
    },
    "description": {
        "short": "Sample Chatbot",
        "full": "Inquiry ChatBot"
    },
    "icons": {
        "outline": "outline.png",
        "color": "color.png"
    },
    "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "bots": [
        {
            "botId": "54321-3592-1234-5668-6789010",
            "scopes": [
                "personal"
            ],
            "isNotificationOnly": false,
            "supportsCalling": false,
            "supportsVideo": false,
            "supportsFiles": false
        }
    ],
    "validDomains": [],
    "webApplicationInfo": {
        "id": "54321-3592-1234-5668-6789010",
        "resource": ""
    },
    "showLoadingIndicator": true,
    "isFullScreen": true,
    "authorization": {
        "permissions": {
            "orgWide": [],
            "resourceSpecific": []
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: I was able to resolve it myself. I removed "showLoadingIndicator" and "isFullScreen" option from Manifest and it is loading fine now from the Apps. Hope it helps someone.